# Rows multiplication needed

Tags: sql, oracle, row, multiplication

Problem description:
Warehouse...
We received 10 pc of one PRODUCT and 3 pc of the same PRODUCT to one container.
They have different USER_DEF_NOTE_2 values.
table INVENTORY:

SKU_ID;QTY_ON_HAND;CONTAINER_ID;USER_DEF_NOTE_2

SKU1;10;K001;OT 15/2013

SKU1;3;K001;WI 14/2011

I need to print 10 x label with first USER_DEF_NOTE_2 value and 3 with second.

Raporting software input is 1 row = 1 label

How to "multiple rows" in this case?

I did standard join on rownum, and it works fine WITH ONE ROW CASE. (I mean i know how to multiple single row*quantity - but i dont know how to multiply 1*qty1 +2*qty2).
My problem is I'm using ROWNUM...and rownum is global.

Any ideas?

Comment: 2? ...Desired output is 1/10, 2/10,3/10,4/10,5/10,6/10,7/10,8/10,9/10,10/10...AND...1/3,2/3,3/3

Comment: select INV.sku_id, INV.user_def_note_2, INV.qty_on_hand, INV.container_id
from inventory INV left join inventory_transaction IT
on inv.sku_id=inv.sku_id
where rownum <= (select sum(qty_on_hand) from inventory where 1=1 and container_id='K001' and sku_id=INV.sku_id and rownum=1)
and INV.container_id='K001';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t.*
from INVENTORY t
join (select level n from dual 
      connect by level <= (select max(QTY_ON_HAND) from INVENTORY)) 
on n <= t.QTY_ON_HAND
```

Answer (score 0):

[Recursive Subquery Factoring clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_10002.htm#i2077142) from 11gR2 to the rescue!

```
create table test(code varchar2(10), n number);

insert into test values('FIRST', 10);
insert into test values('SECOND', 3);

with t(code, num) as (
  select code, 1 num from test
   union all
  select test.code, t.num + 1 num from t, test
   where t.code = test.code and t.num < test.n  
)
select *
  from t
```

Try an example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7352d/4).